# Why doesn't the Xcode compiler auto-error for pointer type safety?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

For example:

```
void modLongerAddress(double *aPtr) {
    *aPtr = 1.11; 
    // or some number that goes beyond the storage capacity of a single precision float
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    float singlePrecision = 1.11;
    modLongerAddress(&singlePrecision);

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I can tell, this only generates a warning. Wouldn't this situation be considered dangerous enough to generate a hard error, or am I missing something?

Comment: "main.c:11:22: Incompatible pointer types passing 'float \*' to parameter of type 'double \*'" - that isn't a warning; its a flat-out error. you're passing `float *` to a function requiring a `double *` My Xcode won't compile that code, and I'm shocked yours *does*. What is your language-standard setting configured to?

Comment: Definitely a warning (I just generated a new project with the code to make sure). Xcode 6.2 (6C101), C Command-line Utility. Either way, knowing that this *is a surprise validates my own surprise as well - I'm checking out settings in Xcode to see if perhaps I changed something?

Comment: And the warning is... ? Add it to your question verbatim please. You can cut/paste warnings/errors out of the build log btw, kinda handy, though you may have to trim the filename down a touch.

Comment: Looks like I found my answer, thanks to your help. There's an explicit setting that appears to be "don't treat this as an error" by default for the version I'm running. Will post answer

Comment: Objective-C is not type safe.  Get over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to WhozCraig's help, I found the setting that was causing this. Appears that in XCode 6.2 (6C101), there is a setting called "Treat incompatible Pointer Type Warnings as Errors" that is set to "**No**" by default.

This setting is found in the Build Settings of the Project, under "**Apple LLVM 6.0 - Warnings - All languages**".

Simply toggling to "**Yes**" did the trick, and the build failed as originally expected.

**EDIT**: It would be a big bonus I suppose if someone could explain why this *would* be set to "**No**" by default? It appears this may not be true for all versions of Xcode?

Comment: Now I'm struggling to remember when I turned mine *on*.  I checked the project settings and its definitely set to Yes. The target settings are unspecified, so its picking up the default (from the project).  I also verified your findings that a new Objective C project indeed has the project and target (by default) set to **No**. I see no earthly reason a non- `void *` pass-thru of incompatible types would not be an error by default with a modern toolchain.

Comment: Agreed, thus my confusion when the build succeeded. I'll leave the edit up for now so perhaps someone might be able to clarify why... or perhaps I should simply ask a new question with the new, more specific findings? Not sure what the best way to leave that "piece" of the question open would be (still relatively new here)

Comment: I think your example should be an error, but there are other cases where type mismatch will cause no harm.  So, seems okay to be a warning to me.... unless you have so many other warning that you are not paying attention to them.